# combining multiple lines into one and start new line after x lines

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a file which has a long list of data with a specific number of lines, below is an example:

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

i need to rearrange the files in which it'll put the output in one line (comma separated) and after x lines insert an new line in the output using shell:

```
111,222,333
444,555,666
777,888,999
```

Thanks
Ali

Comment: `paste -d, - - -  < file`

Comment: @123, add that as an answer